# How do I change the icon of an application in my dash / favorites area?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

This is a picture of my dash in Gnome:

[image]

The second icon is a shortcuts to an Emacs process.  It used to show the Emacs icon but now it just shows the generic icon.

How do I change what icon is associated with a favorite (and ideally make it the same as the application icon showin "Applications"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this program in your favorites?

First you need to find the `.desktop` file.

Enter `gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps` to get all the names of your favorites. For example, here are mine:

```
['firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop']
```

You can find the location of the file with the following command:

```
find ~ /usr/ -name the.name.desktop
```

Replace `the.name.desktop` with the filename you want to look for in your personal and `/usr` folders.

Then, you can edit the `.desktop` file (perhaps as root). Change the line (or add the line) **Icon=...**. There you can put the name of your icon or the whole path to the image you want to use.

Comment: To do a fast search, you should use `locate '*.desktop' | less -S`. You can reduce the amount of output by using a partial name instead of `*`.